# Combining UIImageview and UITextView to create a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uitextview

I would like to have text over a picture. For that I wrote a method that creates a UIView with UIImageView and UITextView as its subviews. I get the UIImage from the graphics context of UIView. This works fine if I save the image to the camera roll. But If I convert the image to NSData and upload it to server, and download the NSData and change it back to UIImage, the image is blank.

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImageView *)sourceImageView addTextFromTextView:(UITextView *)textView {

    UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [parentView addSubview:sourceImageView];
    [parentView addSubview:textView];
    [parentView sizeToFit];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([parentView bounds].size);
    [[parentView layer] drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

The code below works fine, and as the correct image to the camera Roll

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithImage:self.imageView addTextFromTextView:self.textView], nil, nil, nil);
```

However, this code saves a blank image to camera Roll

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithImage:self.imageView addTextFromTextView:self.textView], 1.0);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:imageData], nil, nil, nil);
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I can only assume from the name but self.imageView is a UIImageView property that holds a UIImageView object.

But the UIImageJPEGRepresentation function expects a UIImage object as its first parameter, not a UIImageView object. Thus it returns nothing because the parameters passed are wrong.
UIImage and UIImageView are two different things.

Comment: Yes and I passed a UIImage to UIImageJPEGRepresentation function as a first parameter. [UIImage imageWithImage:self.imageView addTextFromTextView:self.textView] returns a UIImage as you can see on the code.